# How to detect if the event that is generated belongs to Keyboard, Pointer or Form Event?

Tags: javascript

I have developing an application that records the events and replays them. For that I need to identify what kind of event is being generated because mouse, keyboard and form events behave differently from each other.

Right now i am trying to use:
`e instanceof KeyboardEvent` but this doesn't seems to be working. What is the better way of identifying to which event family it belongs to?

Comment: What is not working for you? Any code which can help understand how are you listening for them etc. will be more than welcome.

Comment: I have updated the question. I was not able to detect the event using instanceof because I was trying to detect it on IFRAME. It works fine when doing "e instanceof window.frames[0].KeyboardEvent"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic example for a mouse and keyboard event. You just have to add an eventListener to your desired dom element. And then you have to check if the triggered event `e` is an instance of `MouseEvent` or if it is a `KeyboardEvent`.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('mouse');

button.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
    console.log('a mouse event');
  }
});

const inputField = document.getElementById('keyboard');

inputField.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e instanceof KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('a keyboard event');
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="mouse">MouseButton</button>
<input id="keyboard">
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the `event.detail` allow you to determine if the event was a keypress or mouse event

```
if (event.detail === 0) {
    // keypress event
} else {
    // mouse event
}
```

Read more here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail

Comment: Both return `0` for `FocusEvent` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event `type` property, and then determine where it belongs

```
  const isMouseMoveEvent = e.type === 'mousemove'; // mouse
  const isKeydownEvent = e.type === 'keydown'; // keyboard
  const isSubmitEvent = e.type === 'submit'; // form
```

[Link to MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type#example)